# An Algorithm to read an piece of image row wise and column wise?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, extract

Can someone please help me to read and extract the information of a image row wise and column wise?

My effort is to extract the information from the musical stave.

Example musical stave image:

[image]

For a image consist with several stave line, I need to extract data stave by stave, sequentially.

Can someone please help me along with code snippets? To make an algorithm to extract row by row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information from an image is extracted "row/column wise" no matter what you do; bear in mind that an image is analysed from its pixels, that is, small squares. And it reads all these small squares one after the other.

The difficult part in image processing is dealing with the specific geometrical problems. For example: extracting from this line-by-line reading a complex shape, like one of the staves in your link.

Here you have a small code (written in C#.NET) delivering a simple version of the algorithm you want: it reads row by row or column by column by affecting a single variable (`readVertically`). I guess that it is a good enough introduction to help you:

```
private void readImage(string imagePath)
{
    Bitmap imageBitMap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(imagePath);

    bool readVertically = true; //This flag tells where the image will be analysed vertically (true) or horizontally (false)

    int firstVarMax = imageBitMap.Width; //Max. X
    int secondVarMax = imageBitMap.Height; //Max. Y
    if (!readVertically)
    {
        firstVarMax = imageBitMap.Height;
        secondVarMax = imageBitMap.Width;
    }

    for (int firstVar = 0; firstVar < firstVarMax; ++firstVar)
    {
        for (int secondVar = 0; secondVar < secondVarMax; ++secondVar)
        {
            //Color of the given pixel. Here you can do all the actions you wish (e.g., writing these pixels to other file)
            if (readVertically)
            {
                Color pixelColor = imageBitMap.GetPixel(firstVar, secondVar);
            }
            else
            {
                Color pixelColor = imageBitMap.GetPixel(secondVar, firstVar);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the code. It helped alot
i managed to modify your code by adding following to it.
`byte pixel = pixelColor.B;`

Comment: I am happy to know that it has helped you to develop what you want.